# How can I calculate $\rho_\alpha(z)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, complex-numbers, programming, art

I am trying to design a group of complex functions $\rho_\alpha$ that have a type of symmetry that might look nice if it exists. This is what "symmetry" I want to try.

$$\alpha=a+bi\space\space,\space\space\bar\alpha=a-bi$$ $$\rho_\alpha(z)=\rho_\alpha(\alpha z+\bar\alpha)\tag{1}$$ $$\rho_\alpha'(0)=\frac{\alpha}{|\alpha|}\tag{2}$$

My questions are **does this group of complex functions exist? How can I plot these complex functions using Python, JavaScript, or another programing language? Do they have nice properties?**

I don't understand a lot about complex analysis only bits and pieces. I'm in high school just going into $11$th grade. I love math and I love art. I'm not looking for an exact formula for these functions just how I can compute them, but if there is an exact formula that would be good.

Comment: I don’t think you could compute these functions without solving them in forms of other functions.

Comment: Defining $z_0=\dfrac{\overline α}{1-α}$ and $\tilde ρ_α(z)=ρ_α(z+z_0)$, the conditions are slightly simplified as$$\tilde ρ_α(z)=\tilde ρ_α(αz)\ (\forall z\in\mathbb C),\quad\tilde ρ_α'(-z_0)=\frac α{|α|}.$$

Comment: Further observations: If $\tilde ρ_α$ is continuous, then $\lim\limits_{z→0}\tilde ρ_α(z)$ cannot exist (otherwise $\tilde ρ_α$ is constant). But $\tilde ρ_α$ is bounded in a neighborhood of $0$, so $\tilde ρ_α$ is not meromorphic.

Comment: Maybe we can integrate the function to find it in terms of $z_0$?

Comment: What kind of functions are you looking for? Do they have to be continuous, differentiable, holomorphic, ...? (using @Saad's observation I think it's easy to show that there are many such smooth functions)

Comment: @CarlosEsparza I think I want it smooth so I can plot it in python or another programing language.

Comment: Note that for $\alpha=1$, any function $f$ such that $f(0)=1$ does the job

Answer (score 0):

As Saad in the comments noticed, your condition can be simplified to $\rho(z)=\rho(az)$. This makes the definition near 0 tricky, so let’s ignore discontinuities there.  Letting $f(z)=\rho(e^z)$, we get that $f$ is holomorphic and periodic in $2\pi i$ and $ln(a)$, so it’s an elliptic function. Elliptic functions are a nice class of well understood holomorphic functions with neat properties.

Comment: how would I make a plot this complex function using code?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+z%5E4&lk=3

Comment: in a programing language?

Comment: How to do it depends on the language. Each one has their own libraries. Mathematica/wolfram alpha makes it really simple to plot functions.

Comment: But $ρ(z)=f(\mathop{\mathrm{Ln}}z)$ is not well-defined.

Comment: If f is periodic in $2\pi i$, then all possible definitions of Ln(z) give the same function, so it is well defined for elliptic functions with that period.