# What uses does the product log function have?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, logarithms, inverse-function, applications

I've been looking into complex functions and how to plot them in programing languages like Python and JavaScript. I still am wondering how to do stuff with complex functions like in my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4149164/how-can-i-calculate-rho-alphaz). I was looking around and found an interesting function called the product log function. It's the inverse of $\space xe^x \space$ also written $W(x)$. While trying to find more information on this function I found that it's not the only function that is an inverse to $\space xe^x \space$ there is a whole list of them, when I say list I mean countable infinity. They are labeled $W_n(x)$ where $n$ is an integer. This makes sense since the natural log $\ln(x)$ has a similar property where $\ln(x)+2\pi n$ is also an inverse of $e^x$. You can see the product logs structure quite nicely in it's Riemann surface. It looks like a spiral digging down to one point.[image]

I've seen the natural log be used in several places in science and engineering, but haven't seen the product logs used in many areas or fields. This function looks very nice. **Where are the product logs used in applied fields of study?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the story short, any equation which can write or rewrite
$$a +b x +c \log(d x+e)=0$$ has explicit solutions in terms of the standard Lambert function.
$$x=-\frac{e}{d}+\frac{c }{b}\,W(k) \qquad \text{where} \qquad k=\frac b {cd}\,\exp\Big[\frac{b e-a d}{c d}\Big]$$

If, on the search bar of the site, you just type *Lambert*, you will find $3569$ entries.

Answer (score 0):

A thorough view of Lambert's $W$ function is given by the paper that gave it it's name: Corless, Gonnet, Hare, Jeffrey, Knuth ["On the Lambert $W$ Function"](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02124750), Advances in Computational Mathematics 5, pages 329–359 (1996). A draft copy can be found [here](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/research/tr/1993/03/W.pdf).

It turns out to have a surprising array of uses. Simpler ones are to solve equations in which the indeterminate appears both as a term and in an exponent.